# How to convert generic T from string and get its value passed to another function?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am using many times on my project functions that need a generic to be passed as a parameter. These functions have different inputs, but they all need a T as parameter.

Let me explain with some code what I am currently doing:

```
        switch (tableName)
        {
            case "product":
                foo<Entities.Product>(value);
                break;

            case "customer":
                foo <Entities.Customer>(value);
                break;
        }
```

And this is what I would like to achieve:

```
foo(MyConverter(tableName), value);
```

At the begging although not very elegant I thought I could get away with it, but as the code is growing, there are more functions needing this behavior, not only Foo.

Now I have foo2(value1, value2) foo3(value1, value2, value3) and so on.

I am not really good with delegates, I know there must be some way to implement this automatically, but I just can't figure it out.

Any better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You can only do that using reflection.  There are probably better approaches; what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SLaks yep, reflection is one way to do it but this is for a DB replication engine, where users will call this functions thousand of time per minute. Performace is an issue here. I have edited my question to show how I would like to call each function. Thanks.

Comment: Why does it need to be generic?

Comment: @SLaks a generic is passed to another function depending on the DML action (insert, update or delete). Each table is mapped to a class, that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a dictionary that maps string to Action.

So something like:

```
Dictionary<string, Action<ParamWrapper>> tableActions 
    = new Dictionary<string, Action<ParamWrapper>>();

tableActions.add("product", foo<Entities.Product>);
tableActions.add("customer", foo<Entities.Customer>);

//to call a function, just do this
tableActions["product"](valueWrapper);
```

Where foo is defined as

```
void foo<T>(ParamWrapper paramWrapper) {...}
```

As far as handling a variety of parameters for foo, you could wrap all the parameters into an object of some new type ParamWrapper. When foo is called, it would extract the parameters from the ParamWrapper.

If you do not know all the table names at compile time, or just want this dynamic, then you would want to use reflection, and add the reflected functions to the dictionary.

Comment: Well, this is really close from what I was looking for. The Dictionary idea is neat! However still there is an issue with the foo function since there many of those (foo, foo1, foo2).

Comment: Let me work a little bit on this and get you back later with something. Thanks

Comment: @coffekid: You can use reflection to lazily populate the dictionary.  Beware of threading issues.

Comment: @coffekid: since the dictionary values have the type Action<ParamWrapper>, you can use any function defined as "void bar(ParamWrapper wrapper) {...}". This works with non-generic and type-specified generic functions. So, you may be able to adapt your foo1, foo2, foo3 to suit this.

Comment: After smashing my head to the monitor a couple of times, I think I will go with this approach. It's the fastest and also easy to mantain way. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @SLaks I will be using a static dictionary and the application is ASP MVC 3. I think there shouldn't be any issue with the theadings, do you agree?

Comment: @coffekid: If you ever write to it while processing an HTTP request, you certainly will have problems.

Comment: Then should I execute that code in another thread? Like this: Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { //my code goes here });